# What is the longest effective range artillery weapon ever built?

Tags: war, warfare, weapons, artillery

What is the longest *effective range* artillery weapon ever built, regardless of wether it was actually used in combat?

Comment: For the purposes of this question, what's your definition of "artillery weapon"? Just guns or are you including rockets?

Comment: The standard definition seems to be '*large-calibre guns used in warfare on land*', so no rockets.

Comment: How about rocket assisted shells?

Comment: Please do mention them if they have a lomger range than the ones already named here, however you should add that they are indeed rocket-assisted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It may be the [German V-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-3_cannon), with a maximum range of 165 km. [It was destroyed before it could be fired](http://militaryhistorynow.com/2012/10/12/big-shots-historys-largest-cannons-mortars-and-super-guns/), although several experimental models were used in Luxembourg in 1944-1945. After the war, a U.S.-Canadian group revived the V-3, hoping to use it as a cheap weay to launch objects into space. According to [this military history](http://militaryhistorynow.com/2012/10/12/big-shots-historys-largest-cannons-mortars-and-super-guns/) site:

> Using a testing facility in the Barbados, the HARP team managed to
>   fire a 400-pound non-explosive projectile out over the Atlantic at a
>   speed of 8000 mph (that’s Mach 10). The missile also reached an
>   altitude of 112 miles (nearly 600,000 feet) – a record for
>   highest-flying artillery shot that still stands.

The [Paris Gun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Gun), which was used in combat in 1918, only had a range of 130 km, but even then it couldn't hit a target smaller than a city, and (according to the same site):

> . . . the gunners actually needed to calculate the earth’s rotation when
>   aiming the weapon. Simply put, by the time one of the gun’s shells
>   returned to earth from its then unprecedented 130,000 foot high flight
>   path, the city had moved slightly with the planet’s own rotation.

Comment: Artillery gunners needing to calculate the earth’s rotation as part of their aiming is commonplace. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_artillery_team#FDC_.28Fire_Direction_Center.29) and [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_gun_fire-control_system).

Comment: Fun fact: V-3 stands for Vergeltungswaffe 3 - Revenge Weapon 3 which is one of the most badass names of any weapon ever.

Comment: ...but now that GPS guided shells exist...

Comment: @krb686: True, though from what I see they are only being used for [ranges of around 40 km](http://www.defenseindustrydaily.com/us-begins-ordering-excalibur-ib-gps-guided-sheels-08943/), though I guess longer ranges could eventually be feasible.

Comment: Another interesting aside; the threshold for [Low Earth Orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit) stands around the 100 mile mark.  So perhaps the idea of using it to launch things into space had some merit.  However maintaining a _stable_ orbit at that altitude requires a velocity (apex velocity, not muzzle velocity) of closer to 18,000 mph.

Comment: @aroth: HARP was about getting objects into *space*, not into *orbit*. That's two very different things. Space is easy, it's just 100 klicks up. *Orbit*, on the other hand, requires you do be *fast* at the highest point as well, and is much more difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't care if they were actually used in combat, then the [German V-3 cannons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-3_cannon) would certainly seem to be in with a shot (pardon the pun), with a projected range of 165km.

If you're including land-based guns that fired straight up, then [Project Harp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_HARP) had a 'range' of 180km.

Answer (score 7):

In 2005 the [Advanced Modular Gun Demonstrator](http://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/news/2008/07/mil-080707-saic01.htm) test fired 85 miles or 137km and the shells could go 45km high.  [One article quotes the barrel pressure at 100,000 psi](http://ww2.dcmilitary.com/dcmilitary_archives/stories/051905/34939-1.shtml) which is absurd.  However, it is research equipment, not a practical weapon.

[Here is a presentation about it](http://www.dtic.mil/ndia/2005garm/wednesday/coladonato.pdf) that looks so bad I'd think it were a joke if I didn't know better.

That edges out [the Paris Gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_Gun), which still holds the title of the longest shots fired in anger despite being nearly 100 years old.  It fired a 106 kg shell to a range of 130 km and a maximum altitude of 42 km.  It was purely a terror weapon, only having the accuracy to hit a city.

Comment: I wish they had used Comic Sans.

Comment: @Schwern Since you refer to it, perhaps you should emphasis that the Paris Gun is probably the longest range artillery piece used in anger?

Comment: @AndreasHartmann [Be careful what you wish for](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/264115main_w071408.pdf).

Comment: @ConradTurner Done.

Answer (score 6):

A [railgun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun#U.S._Navy_Tests) currently being developed by the US navy is planned to be integrated onto a ship by 2016 (although the reference is from 2010) with an estimated range of 160 km. It's unclear how far the current technology is able to reach given the probable secrecy of the project. The end goal is to eventually reach as far as 370 km.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the HAARP projects which are well mentioned above which achieved velocities of Mach 10 at an extraordinary altitude of 300,00 feet there is also speculations concerning a "Project Thor" which drops a tungsten rod straight down from outer space...and is perfectly legal actually.

The theoretical power of such a weapon is quite spectacular.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it's not about artillery within the scope defined by the OP.

Comment: [Not "perfectly legal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment#Legality).

Comment: @DevSolar: Violating the *spirit* of a treaty actually is perfectly legal. That is the entire meaning of *violating the spirit of*. It is only unethical.

Comment: [HARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_HARP) and [HAARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Frequency_Active_Auroral_Research_Program) are very different projects.

Answer (score -3):

See the article about [Project Babylon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Babylon) at Wikipedia.org

Comment: Link only answers are unhelpful, please summarise the relevant parts of your links in your answer.